# Entity Framework core generating incorrect SQL on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following models, an `ImprovementNotice`, which can contain a list of `ImprovementNoticeFiles`:

```
public class ImprovementNotice
{
    public ImprovementNotice() {
        this.ImprovementNoticeFiles = new List<ImprovementNoticeFile>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ImprovementNoticeId { get; set; }

    public List<ImprovementNoticeFile> ImprovementNoticeFiles {get; set;}
}

public class ImprovementNoticeFile
{
    [Key]
    public int ImprovementNoticeFileId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public int ImprovementNotice_ImprovementNoticeId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("ImprovementNotice_ImprovementNoticeId")]
    public virtual ImprovementNotice ImprovementNotice { get; set; }
}
```

My context definition:

```
public virtual DbSet<ImprovementNotice> ImprovementNotices { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<ImprovementNoticeFile> ImprovementNoticeFiles { get; set; }
```

I am getting an error when updating on the `SaveChanges` command that Invalid object name 'ImprovementNoticeFile'.

The SQL that is being generated:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (277ms) [Parameters=[@p0='filename.pdf' (Size = 128), @p1='1010'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ImprovementNoticeFile] ([Filename], [ImprovementNotice_ImprovementNoticeId])
      VALUES (@p0, @p1);
      SELECT [ImprovementNoticeFileId]
      FROM [ImprovementNoticeFile]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ImprovementNoticeFileId] = scope_identity();
```

The table name should be `ImprovementNoticeFiles` with an `s` at the end, but the generated SQL is trying to insert into `ImprovementNoticeFile`.

**Update**

This is the code first migration that created the table:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.ImprovementNoticeFiles",
    c => new
        {
            ImprovementNoticeFileId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Filename = c.String(maxLength: 128),
            ImprovementNotice_ImprovementNoticeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ImprovementNoticeFileId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.ImprovementNotices", t => t.ImprovementNotice_ImprovementNoticeId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.ImprovementNotice_ImprovementNoticeId);
```

Comment: You can add `[Table("ImprovementNoticeFiles")]` attribute to the `ImprovementNoticeFile` class.

Comment: That feels like it's covering up a wider issue though!

Comment: What issue would that be? You're already adding attributes to your entity classes. Is this DB first or code first?

Comment: Code first, and good point

Comment: If it's code first, how did you create the tables?

Comment: Using code first migrations, it created the tables correctly

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: So EF created the table with the correct name but won't use it? That doesn't make any sense. Are you sure you didn't make code changes in between?

Comment: How about creating a new migration (you can remove it later)? If it's not empty as I suspect, then definitely you have code which overrides the EF Core default table name(s).